# Listen for GazeInput down event without selecting anything - Google VR Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm working with the **Google VR Unity SDK** and I'm trying to create a VR application where users can switch between multiple ambients(places). I want them to switch to a different ambient just by pushing down the magnetic sensor of the cardboard, pointing anywhere. My problem is that every link (like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YTVsLnK-XU))  I've found, works with objects selection. I've tried adding an *Event Trigger* to my Main Camera  and adding a *Mesh collider* to my building but none of them worked.

So, **¿is it possible to listen for the magnetic sensor pushdown in the full scene without having to select an object?**

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it's simpler than I thought.

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
  //some code
}
```

Thing is googleVR removed magnetic button support since version 0.9.0 and I was using 1.0.3. So if you want to implement a trigger for cardboard's magnetic button you need to use **v0.8.5.**

Answer (score 1):

You could put up a Canvas that's attached to the camera in World Space, so that it always stays in the line of sight. Add a Button to the canvas at the location where the gaze input cursor is, and you should always hit that when triggering.

Comment: This could work, but I didn't try it. Already found the answer to my question, thanks anyway!